# Learning from previous tick and change behavior in next tick

Tags: sequence, updates, netlogo

I am writing a model for water management. Farmers are supposed to see if their behavior is cooperative in water use. Farmers have different level of surface(SW) and groundwater(GW).There is an initial level of cooperation based on expectations from benefit-out. Now I want to have in my model farmers to update behavior from previous behavior. In first tick behavior is determined as cooperative or non-cooperative. In next tick farmer is supposed to change behavior considering behavior in previous tick.

```
globals [TW  well-depth Water-Availbility  ]
Breed [farmers farmer]
farmers-own [ WA sw FW WR WD  Logging salinity expectations benefit-out ]
patches-own [
GW wtd DWS]
to setup
   clear-all
    ask patches [ ifelse random 4 = 0 [
    set dws  distance-from-water-source + random-float 50
    set WTD DWS / depth-WT + random-float 1
    set GW Ground-water + random-float 5.005  +  (100 / wtd)
    set pcolor blue ]

     [ set dws  distance-from-water-source + random-float 100 + 35
       set WTD DWS / depth-WT + 5 + random-float 5
       set GW Ground-water + random-float 5.005  +  (100 / wtd)
       set pcolor red]
        ]
    setup-farmers

  reset-ticks
end
to setup-farmers

create-farmers num-farmers [move-to one-of patches
                             set shape "person"
                             set sw surface-water /  (sum [DWS] of patches in-radius 1 / count patches in-radius 1) + random 100
                            SET WA  sw +  sum [gw] of patches in-radius 1 / count patches in-radius 1 + [gw] of self
                            set logging   100 / dws +  50 / wtd
                            set salinity   .005 * dws + 0.005 * wtd
                            set WD  DWS / minwater-req + 50
                            Set expectations 0.2
                             set benefit-out 0
                            set color Brown
                            if WTD = 0 [stop]
  ]
end
to go

  ask farmers [
  check-wa
  watering-decisions
   update-logging
  update-salinity
  update-wr
  update-water
  update-benefits
  die-end
  new-farmer
  to-stop

  ]

  tick


end
to check-wa

  SET WA  (sw / distance-from-water-source) + sum [gw] of patches in-radius 1 + [gw] of self ;+ random 5
end
to watering-decisions
  if watering-decision = "social-behavior"
  [ ifelse SW > WD [use-sw
                     set-wtd
                      set logging logging + logging / wtd
                      Set salinity salinity  + 0.045 * wtd + random-float .05
                           Set benefit-out benefit-out + (Adjustment-factor / (logging + salinity))
                           set expectations expectations + benefit-out / 1000  + random-float 0.5
                           decide-behavior ]
                           [  ifelse random 2 = 1 [use-sw
                                                    set wtd wtd  - 0.030 + random-float 0.005
                                                    set logging logging + logging / wtd
                                                    set salinity salinity +  (salinity *  wtd)/ 100
                                                    set benefit-out benefit-out + (Adjustment-factor / (logging + salinity))
                                                     set expectations expectations + benefit-out / 1000  + random-float 0.5
                                                     decide-behavior]
                                                                    [use-Gw
                                                                     set wtd wtd + 0.030 + random-float 0.005
                                                                     set logging logging + logging / wtd
                                                                     set salinity salinity +  (salinity *  wtd)/ 1000
                                                                     Set benefit-out benefit-out + (Adjustment-factor / (logging + salinity))
                                                                      set expectations expectations + benefit-out / 1000  + random-float 0.5
                                                                    decide-behavior]] ]

end



to use-GW
  set gw gw - random-float .001
  set-wtd ; need to reconcile with WTD in above writen options.
  Update-water
end
to use-SW
  set sw sw - random-float .001
  Update-water
end
to  Update-water
  set WA SW  + Sum [GW] of patches in-radius 1 + [gw] of self
  ;set WA WA - random-float 0.0005
end
to die-end
  if salinity >= 20 [die]
  if wtd <= 0.5 [die]
 if logging >= 50 [die]

end

to set-wtd
  set wtd wtd  + ( 0.0028 + random-float 0.0015 - random-float .0028)
  ask patches  in-radius 1 [ set wtd [wtd] of myself]

 end

to new-farmer

  if ticks > 0 and ticks mod 5 = 0 and  benefit-out  > sum  [benefit-out] of farmers in-radius 1 / count  farmers in-radius 1
              [hatch 1]

end
to
update-logging
ifelse random 4 = 1 [set wtd wtd + random-float 0.0042
  set logging logging - 0.01]

 [ set WTD WTD - random-float 0.0042
   set logging  logging + random-float 0.022]; linked with annual increas in rainfall every 1 out of 5 years
end
to update-salinity
  ifelse random 4 = 1
  [set salinity salinity + random 0.05]
  [set salinity salinity - random 0.05]
  end

to update-wr
  set wd wd + random-float .01

end
to update-benefits
  set benefit-out benefit-out + random-float 2
  end

to  decide-behavior
  ask farmers [ ifelse expectations >= (sum [expectations] of farmers in-radius 1 / count farmers in-radius 1)
              [ behave-cooperatively]
              [ behave-selfishly]]
end
to  behave-cooperatively
  ifelse wd < sw [ ifelse random 3 <= 1 [use-gw]
                                        [use-sw] set benefit-out benefit-out + 0.5]

  [ifelse random 2 = 1 [use-gw][use-sw] ]

end
to
  behave-selfishly
  Ifelse sw > WD [use-sw
    set benefit-out benefit-out + 0.5
  ]
  [use-GW
  set benefit-out benefit-out + 0.5]

end
to to-stop
if not any? turtles [stop]
end
```

[image: Here is the interface of the model]

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is impossible to answer. You have too many different ideas all mixed up together. Could you please just ask one question, and just show us the code that helps us to understand that question. Pick the most important one, resolve that and then ask a new question.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion @JenB . I have edited my query. I hope now it is understandable.

Comment: Sorry, it's still not a question. You've told us you want to have the behaviour change depending on cooperation in the previous tick and given a block of code and meaningless images. What error is occurring? Which is the line that does the behaviour you want to update? What should it do? What is it doing instead? You might want to look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve but remember that you often can't produce a working example in NetLogo. Just show us the procedure where the error occurs and the procedure that calls the problem one.